# Method "StopDiscovery" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.Adapter1" doesn't exist

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt, raspberry-pi-zero

Running a script [here](https://github.com/Olen/solar-monitor) that connects to 2 Bluetooth adapters and collects data to send via mqtt. Its been running relatively smoothly on my RPi Zero 2 W with LM1010 BT USB adapter (internal wifi and BT adapter for RPi are disabled) for about 2 years now. However, yesterday, I ran just your normal system updates 'sudo apt-get update then upgrade', now when I try to run the script, I get these errors.

I don't know even where to start with this one, and if you can provide some suggestions, that would be great.

```
INFO: Adapter status - Powered: True
INFO: Starting discovery...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gatt/gatt_linux.py", line 156, in stop_discovery
    self._adapter.StopDiscovery()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 141, in __call__
    return self._connection.call_blocking(self._named_service,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject: Method "StopDiscovery" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.Adapter1" doesn't exist


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/solar-monitor/solar-monitor.py", line 84, in <module>
    device_manager.stop_discovery()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gatt/gatt_linux.py", line 161, in stop_discovery
    raise _error_from_dbus_error(e)
gatt.errors.Failed: Method "StopDiscovery" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.Adapter1" doesn't exist
```

ran script, but seems to crash at BLE scan part now after system updates

Comment: Take a look at `service bluetooth status` to see if there are any errors there. Also try using `bluetoothctl` to start the scan to see if that is successful. You might want to keep an eye on: https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-bluetooth/issues

Comment: Hi, yes thanks, when I type that, there are errors:

Jan 26 10:34:02 raspberrypi bluetoothd[713]: profiles/sap/server.c:sap_server_register() Sap driver initialization failed.
Jan 26 10:34:02 raspberrypi bluetoothd[713]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)

Comment: SAP (SIM Access Profile) may not be important. You can remove the error by editing `/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service` and adding `--noplugin=sap` to the `bluetoothd` invocation then restart the service. Did you try starting and stopping the scan with `bluetoothctl` on the command line?

Comment: thanks, you're right I did manage to remove that error with the `--noplugin=sap` in service file. That is not listed anymore, but there is another error listed 

`raspberrypi bluetoothd[377]: Failed to set privacy: Rejected (0x0b)`


With regards to bluetoothctl, bit strange, I can to scan on and off, but sometimes it says adapter not available, and then when I put in `hciconfig`, nothing is listed, restart the RPi, and its back. This intermittent behavior is so strange. For example, start `scan on` and it scans shows devices, then when I `scan off` says `no default controller available`